# Troubleshooting NULL Value Assignments in PUT Update Requests with FASTAPI

Tags: https, sqlalchemy, fastapi, patch, put

My issue revolves around a 'Product' model in my database, where certain values, such as the description, are optional and can either hold a string or a null value. I've created an update function for the product, and the problem arises when I attempt to implement partial updates using either PATCH or PUT methods.

For instance, if I have a product with a description and I wish to update it by removing the description, my approach is to send a request with 'description: null'. However, the problem with this method is that the partial update request interprets it as not wanting to assign null to the description but rather as a signal to not modify the description field at all.

Does anyone know how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_dump and `exclude_unset` / `exclude_defaults` / `exclude_none`? However, I'd probably try to rework this into `description` not being set, if you can see a use case where a user would actually want to remove the description completely - i.e. set it to `null` / `None`. `exclude_unset` would then work as you expect, since no value was provided by your request.

Comment: I have seen that, but i think that the exclude_unset will take my 'description:None' as 'fields that have not been explicitly set'. I think this because setting a field as None for python means that it has not value

Comment: No, that's not what it means - `exclude_unset` means that a value was not provided at all - not that the value provided was `None` or not provided. `exclude_none` does however not return any field set to `None`, however.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exclude_unset` parameter of `model_dump` to implement that behavior.

In your endpoint call `product_data.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)` and it will return you the `dict` that will contain only attributes that were explicitly set in your input data.
Iterate through these attributes and update only them.

So, if you need to update product and leave `description` as it is, then just omit this field in the data you send to endpoint.

If you need to delete description - set this field to Null.

**P.S.:** Use PATCH for partial updates